# HAVING clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to understand why some DBMS systems allow the below while the most don't. Assume table `X` has attributes `name`, `id`, `data`

```
SELECT id, count(*) as count 
FROM TABLE X
GROUP BY id
HAVING count > X.data
```

In most databases, it's illegal to use non-grouping or non-aggregate field in HAVING clause conditional statement. Some systems seem to allow the same. Would you be able to explain why they would have allowed the HAVING condition to use an attribute which may not have a unique value throughout the group?

Referred to database documentation of DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL

```
SELECT id, count(*) as count 
FROM TABLE X
GROUP BY id
HAVING count > X.data
```

Comment: It's also illegal in many systems to use `name` by itself without an aggregate function if the GROUP BY only lists `id`, and not good practice to use it in those that do allow it. Same here. Even if you find it's allowed, _don't do it_, because you never know for sure which `x.data` value from the group you might end up with for the `>` comparison.

Comment: So many things wrong in this query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious GROUP BY error. I have now corrected it to ensure I'm asking the right question

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with this query:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as count 
FROM TABLE X
GROUP BY id
HAVING count > X.data;
```

is that you have `name` in the `SELECT` but `id` in `GROUP BY`.  *Because you are grouping by `id`*, I assume that there are multiple values in `X`.  Hence, this is incorrect syntax.

There are some cases where this is allowed by the standard -- and even in some databases.  However, that requires that `id` be unique in the table (the technical jargon is that the columns in the `SELECT` are *functionally dependent* on the columns in the `GROUP BY`).

The next issue is the use of `count` in the `HAVING` clause.  This is fine conceptually.  However, not all databases may support it.

Finally, you have `x.data` in the `HAVING` clause.  If that is functionally dependent on a subset of the `GROUP BY` keys, then the usage conforms with the standard.  However, that is unlikely in this case.

The standard is quite explicit that `x.data` is out-of-scope after the aggregation.  So, this should result in a syntax error -- and  it does in almost all databases.

There are a dwindling number of databases that support this construct -- happily MySQL no longer supports it by default.  In such databases, they take an *arbitrary* and *indetermine* value of `data` from a row in each group and use that for the comparison.

Comment: My question is actually about the last issue. Why would any database allow x.data to be used in the HAVING condition when they know the value may not be unique in a group. They would have allowed it for some reason initially and probably forced to remove later to adhere to SQL standards

Comment: @user2818113 . . . The database is "broken".  However, MySQL (and to some extent SQLite) allowed this, presumably as a "convenience" for users.  MySQL at least saw the light and realized this creates more confusion.  The proper approach would be an aggregation function, say `any_value()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My professor did say that some systems do allow this behavior for a specific reason and hence exploring why some systems thought it was a convenience for the users when they can't guarantee valid results. Did you happen to know the reason behind or you think it's just a bug that has been fixed later? My professor also mentioned that some systems do allow this behavior today so they believe it has to be allowed for some reason

Comment: @user2818113 . . . It is a bug.  It is precluded by the standard.  Most databases don't do it.  And users find it confusing because they use it inappropriately.  The standard supports functional dependency, as a proper method for simplifying such aggregation queries.